# C Program Doesn't Work Properly (Sets, Arrays, Loops)

Tags: c, arrays, loops, c99

C Program Doesn't Work Properly (Sets, Arrays, Loops)

pls help

Output:

Complement of A to B: 0110010010, 
but is must be: 0100000010

```
printf("A \\ B: ");
for (int i = 0; i < SizeOfU; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SizeOfB; j++)
    {
        if ((U[i] == A[j]) && (A[i] != B[j]))
        {
          i++;
          j = 0;
          printf("1");
        }
```

Comment: Please don't spam language tags.

Comment: What is a "bit line"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SizeOfU; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < SizeOfB; j++)
  {
    if ((U[i] == A[j]) && (A[i] != B[j]))
```

The variable `i` is an index for the array `U[]`, while `j` is an index for the array `B[]`. The problem is that you are using both the index `i` and `j` also for `A[]`. This is clearly wrong; you are in fact reading past the end of `A[]`, but only luck has prevented you from getting a segmentation fault.

Try to write the algorithms without using the array `U[]`. For the union, you can just print out the elements of `A[]`, followed by the elements of `B[]` that are not also in `A[]`.